# How to display an alert when there is no available update (using Adobe Air update framework)

Tags: adobe, air

I'm using Adobe Air update framework to implement auto-update feature in my application. The feature is working great when there is an available update, but when there is no updates no notification/alert is displayed.

is there a way to display an alert when there is no update available ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, listen to StatusUpdateEvent.UPDATE_STATUS on your appUpdater. When it fires, the event will have an 'available' boolean field. If this is false, you can display your own message.